# XML to MySQL: Only adding half of the items?

Tags: mysql, xml

I have an XML file called categories.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<categories>
<category>
<filter>julyfourth</filter>
<name>4th Of July</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>accessories</filter>
<name>Accessories</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>adult-book-clubs</filter>
<name>Adult Book Clubs</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>air-travel</filter>
<name>Air</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>apparel</filter>
<name>Apparel</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter></filter>
<name>Apparel</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>apparel-baby</filter>
<name>Apparel - Baby &amp; Kids</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>big-tall</filter>
<name>Apparel - Big &amp; Tall</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>intimate-apparel</filter>
<name>Apparel - Intimate</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>maternity</filter>
<name>Apparel - Maternity</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>apparel-men</filter>
<name>Apparel - Men</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>plus-size</filter>
<name>Apparel - Plus, Petite &amp; Tall</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>teens</filter>
<name>Apparel - Teens</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>apparel-women</filter>
<name>Apparel - Women</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>appliances</filter>
<name>Appliances</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>automotive</filter>
<name>Automotive</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>local-automotive</filter>
<name>Automotive</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>b2b</filter>
<name>B2B Supplies</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>babies-kids</filter>
<name>Babies &amp; Kids</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>local-babies-kids</filter>
<name>Babies &amp; Kids</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>batteries</filter>
<name>Batteries</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>local-beauty-and-spas</filter>
<name>Beauty &amp; Spas</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>bed-and-bath</filter>
<name>Bed &amp;amp; Bath</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>black-friday</filter>
<name>Black Friday</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>books</filter>
<name>Books &amp; Magazines</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>camera-photo</filter>
<name>Camera &amp; Photo</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>car-rental</filter>
<name>Car Rental</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>childrens-book-clubs</filter>
<name>Childrens Book Clubs</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>christmas</filter>
<name>Christmas</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>clearance</filter>
<name>Clearance</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>college</filter>
<name>College &amp; Education</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>columbus-day</filter>
<name>Columbus Day</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>computers-software</filter>
<name>Computers</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>costumes</filter>
<name>Costumes</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>crafts</filter>
<name>Craft Supplies</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>credit-cards</filter>
<name>Credit Cards</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>cruises</filter>
<name>Cruises</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>cyber-monday</filter>
<name>Cyber Monday</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>dating</filter>
<name>Dating</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>department-stores</filter>
<name>Department Stores</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>diet-fitness</filter>
<name>Diet &amp; Fitness</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>earth-day</filter>
<name>Earth Day</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>easter</filter>
<name>Easter</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>local-education</filter>
<name>Education</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>electronics</filter>
<name>Electronics</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>local-entertainment</filter>
<name>Entertainment</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>event-tickets</filter>
<name>Event Tickets</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>fathers-day</filter>
<name>Father's Day</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>local-financial</filter>
<name>Financial</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>financial</filter>
<name>Financial</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>food-cooking</filter>
<name>Food &amp; Gourmet</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>furniture</filter>
<name>Furniture</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>gift-certificates</filter>
<name>Gift Certificates</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>gifts-flowers</filter>
<name>Gifts &amp; Flowers</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>graduation</filter>
<name>Graduation</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>natural-organic</filter>
<name>Green Living</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>halloween</filter>
<name>Halloween</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>hanukkah</filter>
<name>Hanukkah</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>health-beauty</filter>
<name>Health &amp; Beauty</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>local-health-beauty</filter>
<name>Health &amp; Wellness</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>hobby-collectibles</filter>
<name>Hobby &amp; Collectibles</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>shipping-deadlines</filter>
<name>Holiday Shipping Deadlines</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>home-improvement</filter>
<name>Home Improvement</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>local-home-services</filter>
<name>Home Services</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>hotel-travel</filter>
<name>Hotel</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>house-home</filter>
<name>House &amp; Home</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>insurance</filter>
<name>Insurance</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>internet-services</filter>
<name>Internet Services</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>jewelry</filter>
<name>Jewelry</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>kitchen</filter>
<name>Kitchen</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>local-legal-services</filter>
<name>Legal Services</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>lighting</filter>
<name>Lighting</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>local</filter>
<name>Local Deals</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>luggage</filter>
<name>Luggage</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>mothers-day</filter>
<name>Mother's Day</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>movies-music</filter>
<name>Movies &amp; Music</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>musical-instruments</filter>
<name>Musical Instruments</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>local-nightlife</filter>
<name>Nightlife</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>office-supplies</filter>
<name>Office Supplies</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>outdoors</filter>
<name>Outdoors</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>party-supplies</filter>
<name>Party Supplies</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>pets</filter>
<name>Pet Supplies</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>local-pets</filter>
<name>Pets</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>phones-wireless</filter>
<name>Phones &amp; Wireless</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>local-photography</filter>
<name>Photography</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>pink-ribbon-shop</filter>
<name>Pink Ribbon Shop</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>printers</filter>
<name>Printers &amp; Ink</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>local-professional-services</filter>
<name>Professional Services</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>local-public-services</filter>
<name>Public Services</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>local-real-estate</filter>
<name>Real Estate</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>satellite</filter>
<name>Satellite TV &amp; Radio</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>school-supplies</filter>
<name>School Supplies</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>shoes</filter>
<name>Shoes</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>local-shopping</filter>
<name>Shopping</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>software</filter>
<name>Software</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>sports</filter>
<name>Sporting Goods</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>local-sporting-goods</filter>
<name>Sports &amp; Recreation</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>st-patricks</filter>
<name>St. Patrick's Day</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>sunglasses</filter>
<name>Sunglasses</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>taxes</filter>
<name>Tax Services</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>thanksgiving</filter>
<name>Thanksgiving</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>tools-hardware</filter>
<name>Tools &amp; Hardware</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>toys</filter>
<name>Toys &amp; Games</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>local-travel</filter>
<name>Travel</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>travel</filter>
<name>Travel</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>vacations</filter>
<name>Vacation Packages</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>valentines</filter>
<name>Valentines Day</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>video-games</filter>
<name>Video Games</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>web-hosting</filter>
<name>Web Hosting &amp; Domains</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>weddings</filter>
<name>Weddings</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>wine-spirits</filter>
<name>Wine &amp; Spirits</name>
</category>
<category>
<filter>yard-garden</filter>
<name>Yard &amp; Gardening</name>
</category>
</categories>
```

I'm using simplexml to parse it and add it to the mysql database:

```
<?php
include "../scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$rss =  simplexml_load_file("categories.xml");
    if ($rss) { // Feed is valid and well formed
        foreach ($rss->category as $category) {
            $name = $category->name;
            $fmtc_categoryid = $category->filter;
            $parentid = '0';
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tblCategories SET categoryid = '',name = '$name',fmtc_categoryid = '$fmtc_categoryid',parentid = '$parentid'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql) or die();       
        }
    }   
?>
```

Its adding it to the database, however, its only adding about half the entries in the XML file, I've run it numerous times, and it only adds up to and including "Event Tickets". Very confusing, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Lol you didnt have to post the whole file

Comment: You could `die(var_dump($rss))` and see if all the data is being parsed out correctly.

Comment: @AdrianCornish: Lol, well if I didn't post the whole thing Hielo wouldn't have been able to help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the apostrophe in "Father's Day".  You need to escape the data before you insert into the db. Change:

```
$name = $category->name;
$fmtc_categoryid = $category->filter;
```

to

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($category->name);
$fmtc_categoryid = mysql_real_escape_string($category->filter);
```

For your reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much. I will have to remember that trick for the future.

Answer (score 0):

How about import into a temporary table then select the rows you want